# Dockerfile ADD statement can't acces my src folder when building inside a circleci job

Tags: docker, dockerfile, circleci

I've started using circleci for CI (I'm a newbie) and I want to build a docker image and push it to dockerhub inside a circleci job.

the problem is the ADD statement of the dockerfile, the error say

```
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder814373370/app/build: no such file or directory
```

`docker build` work fine in local. The problem seems to be the 'remote environment' create by circleci to execute docker cmd inside a job (when the job is executing inside a container). I tried multiple things to share my folder to the remote environment but nothing has worked. I also tried to execute my job inside a 'machine' to get rid of the 'remote environment' but it gives me more errors.

I think I can achieve it by storing my project online in another job and then adding the folder by https inside the dockerfile. But I'm pretty sure there is a faster way, I just don't see it.

here my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt-get update -yq && apt-get -yq install nodejs npm && npm install serve -g  

ADD app/build/ /app

EXPOSE 5000 

CMD serve -s /app -l 5000
```

and my circleci job:

```
working_directory: ~/project/
  docker:
    - image: circleci/buildpack-deps:stretch
  steps:
    - checkout
    - setup_remote_docker
    - run:
        name: Build Docker image
        command: sudo docker build . -t $IMAGE_NAME:latest
```

Comment: I don't know anythging about CircleCI, but it seems to me it is trying to build your image in the directory `/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder814373370/`, which is probably a checkout of your repository, and does not contain the path `app/build/`. Where should that directory be? Is it in your repository?

Comment: the path `app/build/` is in my source code at the same level of my dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieve it by storing artifacts in another job and then adding the folder by https with curl and wget in a RUN statement of the dockerfile